# Can´t upload code to Arduino Uno using stino and Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

Tags: arduino, sublimetext2, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed stino on [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 2 succesfully, but when I try to upload my code to [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno), the output is the following:

> Uploading /home/lucas/Arduino_Build/programa_teste/programa_teste.hex to Arduino Uno...
>   avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
>   ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   [Stino - Error while uploading.]

I have the Arduino [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) installed, and it is working fine, only Sublime Text can´t upload the code.

Comment: Do you run the Arduino IDE with `sudo`? Permission denied means it might need admin permission.

Comment: @Bibhas - running the arduino editor with `sudo` to deal with permissions issues is VERY MUCH THE **WRONG SOLUTION**. That is akin to fixing an issue with the tires on your car by setting it on fire, and pretending it was like that when you found it. The OP needs to properly fix the permissions issue, not just plaster over it with a security hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, as @Bibhas says, your problem is that `/dev/ttyACM0` is having the wrong permissions, and that has nothing to do with Arduino or sublime text. It's the linux kernel who creates character devices per default with no user permissions.

But good thing is that it can be changed!

The fast and easy solution is to add your current user to the `dialout` group:

```
sudo adduser YOU dialout
```

where YOU is your username and then log out and log back in to have those new permissions propagated into your shells.

*Hint:*

There's a solution that is a bit more complicated, is to create a udev rule such as:

/etc/udev/rules.d/48-arduino.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM!="usb_device", ACTION!="add", GOTO="arduino_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0036", MODE="660", GROUP="arduino", SYMLINK+="arduino.leonardo"
LABEL="arduino_end"
```

which creates a `/dev/arduino` device readable and writable by the arduino group, that you need to create (or you can use the default `dialout` group which is perfectly fine):

```
addgroup arduino
adduser YOU arduino
```

and then reload your rules:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

The nice thing about that second hint is that when you unplug replug your arduino, you won't have it change device number oddly, it will be kept to the name. If you're not using an arduino leonardo, you can check your device idvendor/idproduct using lsusb:

```
% lsusb                
…                      ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓
Bus 006 Device 105: ID 2341:0036 Arduino SA 
…
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks @zmo, your first piece of advice worked for me!

Comment: you're welcome, but you should definitely try out the second advice, as it'll avoid you troubles when connecting your device!

Answer (score 0):

Accoding the [Troubleshooting doc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload), I use

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty yourUserName
sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourUserName
```

fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today, and the incredible happend. The USB cable gave power to the Arduino, but doesn't allow the communication. The solution for us was to change the USB cable, and after that everything worked